# Auto Gen Vertices not working?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew

I am creating a program using opengl to define 4 vertices (creating a box) and then shifting it over and generating a new one effectively creating a larger box of smaller boxes. But when I run it, the vertices go crazy and I reduced it down so you guys can understand what I mean.  I want it to be 3 seperate boxes but using wireframe you can clearly tell that it is 2 boxes connected by one.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glut.h>
using namespace std;

//variables
const float bork = 0.2;
const float blep = -0.2;
float a = 0.2;
float b = -0.2;
float c = 0.2;
float d = -0.2;
float e = 0.2;
float f = -0.2;
float i = 0.2;
float h = 0.2;
float x = 0;
float y = 0;
float z = 0;
float r = 0;
float g = 0; 
float u = 0;
float base = 0;


void stopGen() {
  cout << "stopped generating" << endl;
}

//Functions for generating he vertices!
void generateVerticesYu() {
  glVertex2f(bork, c);
  glVertex2f(bork, d);
  glVertex2f(blep, c);
  glVertex2f(blep, d);
  glColor3ub(r, g, u);
}
void generateVerticesXr() {
  glVertex2f(e, c);
  glVertex2f(e, d);
  glVertex2f(f, c);
  glVertex2f(f, d);
  glColor3ub(r, g, u);
}
void generateVerticesXl() {
  glVertex2f(a, c);
  glVertex2f(a, d);
  glVertex2f(b, c);
  glVertex2f(b, d);
  glColor3ub(r, g, u);
}
void generateVerticesYd() {
  glVertex2f(bork, c);
  glVertex2f(bork, d);
  glVertex2f(blep, c);
  glVertex2f(blep, d);
  glColor3ub(r, g, u);
}


//Keybinds for wireframe and camera movement
void special(int key, int, int)
{
  const float step = 0.1;

  if (GLUT_KEY_LEFT == key)//camera left
    x -= step;

  if (GLUT_KEY_RIGHT == key)//camera right
    x += step;

  if (GLUT_KEY_UP == key)//camera up
    y += step;

  if (GLUT_KEY_DOWN == key)//camera down
    y -= step;

  if (GLUT_KEY_SHIFT_L == key)//wireframe ON

    cout << "Wireframe Enabled" << endl;
/*
  if (GLUT_KEY_CTRL_L == key)//wireframe OFF
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
    glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);
    cout << "Wireframe Disabled" << endl;
    */
  if (GLUT_KEY_END == key)//RED rgb value UP
    ++r;
    cout << "Red:";
    cout << r << endl;

  if ((GLUT_KEY_END + GLUT_KEY_SHIFT_R) == key)//RED rgb value DOWN
    --r;

  if (GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP == key)//GREEN rgb value UP
    ++g;

  if ((GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP + GLUT_KEY_SHIFT_R) == key)//GREEN rgb value DOWN
    --g;

  if (GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN == key)//BLUE rgb value UP
    ++u;

  if ((GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN + GLUT_KEY_SHIFT_R) == key)//BLUE rgb value DOWN
    --u;

  glutPostRedisplay();

}
//renders the vertices
void display()
{
  glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
  glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_LINE);
  glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glTranslatef(x, y, z);
  //actual rendering starts here
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
  if (base != 5) {
    base += 1;
    generateVerticesXl();
    a -= 0.4;
    cout << "a:";
    cout << (a) << endl;
    b -= 0.4;
    cout << "b:";
    cout << (b) << endl;
    generateVerticesXr();
    e += 0.4;
    cout << "e";
    cout << (e) << endl;        
    f += 0.4;
    cout << "f";
    cout << (f) << endl;
  }
/*      do {


    generateVerticesYd();
    c += 0.4;
    cout << "c:";
    cout << (c) << endl;
    d += 0.4;
    cout << "d:";
    cout << (d) << endl;

    generateVerticesYu();
    i += 0.4;
    cout << "i";
    cout << (i) << endl;
    h += 0.4;
    cout << "h";
    cout << (h) << endl;


    } while (base != 6);*/

  glEnd();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}

//main loop for everything!
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
  glutCreateWindow("McDank");
  glutSpecialFunc(special); 
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  //glutIdleFunc();<----TO BE DETERMINED!
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

There may be better ways of doing this but this is how I want to do it right now, but im getting this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExChk.png)

Also, if I press any key, it expands it like it is trying to generate another square: [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOOJU.png)

Comment: Don't use `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` if you don't want a triangle strip. You should also be aware that the GL functions you're using here are deprecated _since a decade_ by now.

Comment: @derhass thank you i will try that and ik they are im just trying to get an understanding of how it all works

Comment: it builds on linux box with `g++  box.cpp  -lglut -lGL' with //#include "stdafx.h"